# Bigtable and Compound Primary Keys

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, bigtable, google-cloud-datastore

I know GAE Datastore is not SQL, and that the notion of a compound primary key isn't a 1:1 mapping to SQL. But I think I want to create something like one and am looking for the consensus on how that works. Here is my data model:

- Car Company

  - primary key: company name
- Model

  - primary key: company name, model name
- Car

  - primary key: company name, model name, VIN

In SQL, on Model "company name" and "model name" would be my primary key ("company name" of which would also be a foreign key). Then Car would have a compound foreign key `Car(company name, model name) -> Model(Company name, model name)`.

In the `ndb` library, a [Key](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/keyclass) is actually a set of key/value pairs, but that looks to be related to ancestors, used for transactions. I don't need transactions for this (and in fact, since ancestors limit the whole entity group to about one transaction per second, I don't want to use ancestors here at all). So my questions are:

1. Is the fact that a Key is a set of key-value pairs a way to use it as a compound primary key equivalent, or does it automatically create an ancestor relationship? Is it possible to have a Key with multiple components without using ancestors and limiting my transaction rate? Are these tied inexorably together, or unrelated and mostly just used together?
2. How do people generally handle this notion in Google Datastore/Bigtable? I can fake a compound key by joining the keys into one string (instead of a list like `[Ford, Focus]` I can just make a string like `"Ford/Focus"`), is that what most people do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your two questions:

1. I'm not familiar with `ndb` but Keys in Datastore are made up of a hierarchy of Kind-ID (Long) or Kind-name (String) pairs.  So, yes, creating that set of key-value pairs will impose entity groups, such that the Car would be in the Model's entity group, which would be in the Car Company's entity group. [This page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities) explains in more detail.
2. Your data model will really depend on how you want to query it and update it, but it's worth bearing in mind that Datastore won't enforce any constraints on your data, your application will need to do that.  So, yes, creating a unique string, such as `ford.focus` could be one way to create a Model identifier.  You may then use something like `ford.focus.12345` as a Car identifier.  Or you could just allow Datastore to create you a Long ID automatically and then have your Car entity store a Key to its Model, which in turn could have a Key referencing its Car Company entity.  You may wish to have some redundancy over normalisation and have keys to both the Model and the Car Company in your Car entity - again, it depends on what data you need to query/fetch and how often.

The important thing to remember is that fetching by key is better than querying, so your application's requirements will have a bearing on your entity model.

Comment: "The important thing to remember is that fetching by key is better than querying" this is exactly my impetus for asking, yeah. Thanks!